# jQuery accordion expanded

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create an accordion with jQuery from this example

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion

The markup is the same, i.e.

```
<div id="accordion">
   <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
   <div>First content</div>
   <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
   <div>Second content</div>
</div>
```

And I have script file enqueued correctly, which has the following content:

```
$ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

But I get this error in the console output

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#accordion").accordion()')
```

The result being all divs are expanded, i.e not clickable.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for :  http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/faEg9/

Your dependent js files are not present I suppose!

```
 <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="accordion">
   <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
   <div>First content</div>
   <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
   <div>Second content</div>
</div>​

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#accordion").accordion();
  });​
```

Comment: But jQuery + UI is already included in Wordpress. I can see the files being loaded in the Web Inspector. I tried putting your links in my header.php and I can see them being loaded too, but it doesn't help. I think it's a conflict and I need to disable the loading of the Wordpress jQuery if I were to include your links in header.php.

Comment: Ok  let the wp jquery load of its not too old version. Also what about the jquery-ui.css?

Comment: Actually, if u have a Public URL of ur Wordpress , I can take a look!

Comment: No I don't have a public URL unfortunately. I see in the Web Inspector that everything but the jquery accordion is loaded. That is probably the reason behind.

Comment: I solved it by deregistering the jquery-ui-accordion and registering it again by specifying the path to it, like so wp_register_script('jquery-ui-accordion', path)

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
//$ = jQuery; 
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     $("#accordion").accordion();
});
```

Comment: -1, bad answer honestly. Not trying to discourage you. But more thought needs to go in before putting up an answer. 

@Eswar's answer is correct.